# Existence of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is assuming that a function with certain domain and range exists leads to wrong solutions?

I'm trying to proof that cardinality of image sets is less than that of the domain set for finite sets.

So if $f:X\to Y$ is a function and X has cardinality n then $|f(X)|\leq|X|$.

So I restricted f to it's image and constructed the following function
      $f$$_i$$:X\to f(X)$.

The function     $g:f(X)\to I$.

and the function   $h:X\to I$.

Where $ I $ is the indexing set.
Then $h=g \circ f$ and since h is bijection then $f$ is injection and $g$ is surjection which contradicts the theorem.

So what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: Consider X=Y=I={-1,0,1} and f(x)=|x|. How would you define g? Does $h=g \circ f$ really hold?

Comment: Also if g is a surjection we know $|f(X)| \geq |I|=|X|$. This does not contradict $|f(X)| \leq |X|$ but both statements together imply equality. What would equality mean? (You used this assumptions in your proof, even though it doesn't necessearily hold true/doesn't hold true in general).

Comment: No because if we defined h to be the identity function so to be bijective then $h=g \circ f$ doesn't exist for -1 or 1 or 0 according how we define g . Then does this mean I can't assume g to exist or what.

Comment: In the book it asked for a proof that if $h=g \circ f$ is a bijection then f must be injective and g must be surjective.I didn't assume that.

Comment: You can still define g s.t. g(y) is in the preimage of {y} under f, i.e., s.t. f(g(y))=y for all y in f(X). However there might be serveral ways to choose g(y) for some y (in my example for 1), so $ g \circ f=id $ will only hold if you restrict on the elements you had chosen. If you assume otherwise you actually assume that f is injective.

Comment: You did assume that h is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks but is it valid to assume the existence of g.

Comment: h is bijection by definition of cardinality.

Comment: True, as I said: You can devine g and can obviously define 
h accordingly as the concenation with f. But why do you think it's valid to assume that h is a bijection? My example should show you that h(X) is a subset of I, but not necessarily the whole set (h is not the identity, or if you set h as identity then you don't have $h= g \circ f$).

Comment: You are missing the fact that codomain and image are not the same thing here. h is not a bijection by definition of cardinality. A bijection is a function $b: X \to Y$ s.t. b is injective and surjective and h is neither. (For finite sets with same cardinality injectivity and surjectivity coincide).

Comment: I is indexing set so if X has Cardinality n then I={1,2,3,....,n} so h needs to be bijection for X to have Cardinality n. so h is bijective.

Comment: No. You are assuming that h is the identity. I can define $ h:\{-1,0,1\} \to \{-1,0,1\}, \ x \mapsto 0$. This is not a bijection is it?

Comment: By the way: You can easily define $h: f(X) \to f(X), \ y \mapsto (f \circ g) (x)$, this is the identity and you can use your statement about g being injective.

Comment: Isn't that question calling for pigeonholes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X = f^{-1}f(X) = \cup \{ f^{-1}(y) : y \in f(X) \}$
As each f$^{-1}$(y) is not empty,
there can be no more than n of them.
Thus |f(X)| <= n.

The proposition holds in general.
Indexing is often a clumsy approach.